# How to jump into the other window immediately when C-x 2/3 in Emacs

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

When I use `C-x 2/3` to open a new window in Emacs, I usually want to do something in the other window, such as shell, open a buffer or visit a new file, but I always change into the other window manually. Is there a way(maybe `defun` a new function in `.emacs`, but I'm new to Emacs) that I can switch my point into the other window immediately after `C-x 2/3` just like when you open a new tab and switch to it immediately in a browser???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just wrapping the function using something like this:

```
(defun my-split-window-below ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((win (split-window-below)))
    (set-frame-selected-window (selected-frame) win)))
```

You could also do `defadvice` on `split-window-below` using `after`, and have it select the window, but I'm not sure that it's a better solution.